# Is there a version of Beauty and the Beast where the bad sisters get punished?

Tags: identification-request

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast), there are several versions of the fairy tale Beauty and the Beast. Do any of them punish the bad sisters? If so, were the punishments "in line with" cultural expectations of what a reasonable punishment would be?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Whether there are multiple version of Beauty and the Beast is a valid question. However, whether the bad sisters should get punished is a separate question that I would keep out of this. (It also sounds rather opinion based.)

Comment: Is my edit ok? I tried to make the last part a little easier to answer objectively - basically what I was going for was whether a reasonable person at the time that the version was published would have considered the punishment reasonable. (Please excuse the textualism :) ).

Answer (score 4):

I am using as a reference for this answer *Beauty and the Beast Tales from Around the World* by Heidi Anne Heiner, which is 830 pages long -- so, yes, there are a few variants.

The thing is that *Beauty and the Beast* itself is a literary re-telling of a very old tale.  It is considered a unique subtype of that tale (with a fair number of variants) because of its psychological plot -- usually the heroine has to go on a long quest or otherwise through great effort undo the effects of her violating a prohibition.

The oldest written version we have of the general tale is the tale of *[Cupid and Psyche](https://www.surlalunefairytales.com/a-g/beauty-beast/stories/cupid3.html)* where, after the sisters tricked Psyche, and Cupid had fled,

> When she had recovered some degree of composure she looked around her, but the palace and gardens had vanished, and she found herself in the open field not far from the city where her sisters dwelt. She repaired thither and told them the whole story of her misfortunes, at which, pretending to grieve, those spiteful creatures inwardly rejoiced. "For now," said they, "he will perhaps choose one of us." With this idea, without saying a word of her intentions, each of them rose early the next morning and ascended the mountains, and having reached the top, called upon Zephyr to receive her and bear her to his lord; then leaping up, and not being sustained by Zephyr, fell down the precipice and was dashed to pieces.

The first actual version of the specific tale, by Gabrielle-Suzanne Barbot de Villeneuve, has Beauty forgiving her sisters -- who aren't really her sisters in this tale -- but it is better known in the (heavily redacted) [version](https://www.surlalunefairytales.com/a-g/beauty-beast/stories/beaumont.html) by Jeanne-Marie Leprince de Beaumont which includes

> As to you, ladies,” said the fairy to Beauty’s two sisters, “I know your hearts, and all the malice they contain. Become two statues, but, under this transformation, still retain your reason. You shall stand before your sister’s palace gate, and be it your punishment to behold her happiness; and it will not be in your power to return to your former state, until you own your faults, but I am very much afraid that you will always remain statues. Pride, anger, gluttony, and idleness are sometimes conquered, but the conversion of a malicious and envious mind is a kind of miracle.”

> Immediately the fairy gave a stroke with her wand, and in a moment all that were in the hall were transported into the prince’s dominions. His subjects received him with joy. He married Beauty, and lived with her many years, and their happiness—as it was founded on virtue—was complete.

In neither story -- or in any of the others where the sisters are punished -- is there any suggestion that the punishment is unreasonable, as opposed to the way in de Villeneuve's version the fairy who cursed the prince to be a beast (as punishment for refusing to marry her) is derided.